# Divolte collector not returning default values

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, clickstream

I'm new to divolte collector. After setting it up to track custom events, for some reason divolte collector does not track the default values it tracks from the code.

Only either one words, leaving everything to default or mapping custom fields one by one, not both. Am I missing something or how should I fix it?